# Render fields from different different sObjects

Tags: apex

**Screenshot NO : 1**[image]
**Screenshot NO : 2**[image]
**Screenshot NO : 3**[image]

I have developed visualforce page and controller for sObjects but when i go through the one object to another object the first field is rendered with second object. see below the issue.

Visualforce:

```
<apex:actionfunction name="Load" action="{!Load}" rerender="sectionsPanel" />
                          <apex:commandButton action="{!Load}" value="" id="theButton"  image="{!URLFOR($Resource.Plus_img)}" style=" height:30px;  width:50px;" />

               <apex:outputPanel id="sectionsPanel">   
                <apex:repeat value="{!lstSections}" var="section">
               <apex:pageBlock id="pb2">
               <apex:pageblocksection columns="4" id="filterPBS1"  rendered="{!Fieldoptions.size != null}" >        
                    <apex:pageblocksectionitem dataStyle="width:0%" labelStyle="width:7%" >
                        <apex:outputLabel value="Fields"/>
                        <apex:selectList value="{!SelectedField}" multiselect="false" size="1" >
                            <apex:selectOptions value="{!Fieldoptions}" />
                        </apex:selectList>
                    </apex:pageblocksectionitem>

                     <apex:pageblocksectionitem dataStyle="width:0%" labelStyle="width:7%">
                        <apex:outputLabel value="operator"/>
                        <apex:selectList value="{!SelectedField}" multiselect="false" size="1">
                            <apex:selectOptions value="{!Fieldoptions}" />
                        </apex:selectList>
                    </apex:pageblocksectionitem>

                    <apex:pageblocksectionitem dataStyle="width:0%" labelStyle="width:7%" >
                        <apex:outputLabel value="Condition"/>
                        <apex:inputText value="{!text1}" id="theTextInput"/>
                    </apex:pageblocksectionitem>

                    <apex:pageblocksectionitem labelStyle="width:2%">
                            <apex:commandButton action="{!toggleContent}" value="" id="theButton"  image="{!URLFOR($Resource.minus_icon1)}" style=" height:30px;  width:50px;"/>
                    </apex:pageblocksectionitem>
              </apex:pageblocksection>
          </apex:pageBlock>
          </apex:repeat>
          </apex:outputPanel>
```

Class:

```
Public class MassUpdate{
  public String val{get;set;}
  public String SelectedSobject{get;set;}
  public String oldSelectedSobject{get;set;}
  public String SelectedField{get;set;}
  public String text1{get;set;}
  public List<SelectOption> options{get;set;}
  public List<SelectOption> Fieldoptions{get;set;}
  public List<String> lstSections {get;set;}
  public String pageblocksectionid{get;set;}
  public integer cnt{get;set;}
  public String sectionsPanel{get;set;}

    public MassUpdate(){
        cnt=0;
        oldSelectedSobject='';
        pageblocksectionid ='Pb0';
        lstSections = new List<String>();

        List<Schema.SObjectType> gd = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().Values();    
        options = new List<SelectOption>();
        for(Schema.SObjectType f : gd)
        {
           options.add(new SelectOption(f.getDescribe().getname(),f.getDescribe().getLabel()));
        }
    }

    public pagereference Load(){

        pageblocksectionid ='Pb'+ cnt++;
        Fieldoptions= new List<SelectOption>(); 
        if(SelectedSobject!=oldSelectedSobject){
            Fieldoptions.clear();
            oldSelectedSobject=SelectedSobject;
            lstSections.add(pageblocksectionid);
    //  }else{
    //      lstSections.add(pageblocksectionid);
        }
        if(Fieldoptions.size() <= 0){
            GeField();
        }
       //  system.debug('***Fieldoptions.size()******'+Fieldoptions.size());
    return null;
    }

    private void GeField(){
        Map<String,Schema.SObjectType> fMap= Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = fMap.get(SelectedSobject).getDescribe().fields.getMap();
        if (fieldMap.size() > 0)
            for(Schema.SObjectField sfield : fieldMap.Values()){
                Fieldoptions.add(new SelectOption(sfield .getDescribe().getname(),sfield.getDescribe().getLabel()));
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem isn't clear.  What is the expected behaviour, and what is happening instead?  What does "the first field is rendered with second object" mean?  A screenshot may help.

Comment: Please see my edited question. (I have uploaded screeshot with results)

Comment: Did you got my point where am i stuck ? @SpongeBob

Answer (score 0):

hey the reason might be this line :  Fieldoptions.clear(); everytime its loaded , it just clears the selected list and rerenders on the page

Check rerender  and rendered values as well on page .